# Need help hiding some code

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, content-management-system, virtuemart

I am working on a Joomla(1.5.14)/Virtuemart(1.1.3) website and I have run into a problem implementing some AdWords code snippets due to being unable to use PHP in the Category Description areas in Virtuemart.

This is what I wanted to achieve.

I have the main AdWords snippet in the main 'index.php' file for the website as follows:

```
<?php if ($HideAdWords != "yes") : ?>

<!-- Google Code for Every user Remarketing List -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = ###;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "666666";
var google_conversion_label = "###";
var google_conversion_value = 0;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<?php if ($_SERVER['HTTPS']) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
<?php } else { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
<?php }?>

</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<!--<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="###"/>-->
</div>
</noscript>

<?php endif; ?>
```

On certain pages I included a different AdWords code along with the following PHP snippet, wanting to remove the original piece of code from the page when browsing this page:

```
<?php
$HideAdWords = "yes";
?>
```

This did do what I wanted it to however on most of the pages I need to apply this I am not able to use PHP, when entering PHP into a category description in Virtuemart, upon saving changes it comments out any PHP code and makes it useless.

I have tried searching as much as I can, and tried the Joomla/Virtuemart specific websites/forums.  I managed to get JavaScript working in these category description areas so I was wondering if maybe I can replicate this effect with JavaScript or maybe you guys can think of a better solution?

I hope I have been clear, any help would be really appreciated.

Kind Regards.

*edit: fixed unspecific title.

Comment: Could'nt you just write the `if (hideAdWords)`-block in javascript? You would only need to access the variable and pass it to javascript, somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in JavaScript, use this snippet in your main page:

```
<script>
(function() {
  if(window.hideAdWords) return;
  var google_conversion_id = "###",
      google_conversion_language = "en",
      google_conversion_format = "3",
      google_conversion_color = "666666",
      google_conversion_label = "###",
      google_conversion_value = 0;

  document.write(unescape("%3Cscript%20type%3D%22text/javascript%22%20src%3D%22//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}());
</script>
```

Then your PHP just needs to write out:

```
<script>
  hideAdWords = <?php print ($HideAdWords == "yes" ? 'true':'false'); ?>;
</script>
```

If you aren't able to guarantee that the hideAdWords line would be printed before the function block, you can change the function block so that it is wrapped in an event handler that fires when the page has finished loading (this example uses jQuery but you can easily do the same thing with an addEventListener call):

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
  if(window.hideAdWords) return;
  var google_conversion_id = "###",
      google_conversion_language = "en",
      google_conversion_format = "3",
      google_conversion_color = "666666",
      google_conversion_label = "###",
      google_conversion_value = 0;

  document.write(unescape("%3Cscript%20type%3D%22text/javascript%22%20src%3D%22//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E"));
});
</script>
```

Given that the only difference between the SSL and HTTP urls is the schema, you can drop the protocol and start the url with a double slash to just use the http or https that the current page has been accessed through.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help you are a lifesaver!  However I can't get it to work, when copying it exactly as you're written it, it is still printed out on the page.

Looks like this:
http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/9100/16238576.jpg

Comment: Have you changed the google_conversion_id and google_conversion_label values to be the real values? If they really are supposed to be three hashes then they'll need to be wrapped in quotes (as above now)

Comment: Oops don't know how I miss that but it is still happening unfortunately. http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/5091/46287193.jpg

Comment: It looks like you're missing the opening script tag of the second script block, here's a working version for you http://jsfiddle.net/steveukx/n9fQe/

Comment: I still can't get it, I apologise for wasting your time, I am not doing well heh. http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/1138/60762760.jpg

Comment: A few questions... what about it isn't working? do you get any errors in the console? have you tried using the alert instead of document.write to see if you get that far? Assuming that you're using Chrome, have a look in the Network tab of the developer tools to see if conversion.js gets loaded as it does in the fiddle linked above.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help I realised why it was still loading the conversion.js file..because I left it as false instead of true.  Please excuse my ignorance, I am forever grateful for you help today!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do that in js, you could use in js:

```
//js part included in php file that loads as common file to all, like footer or header
var hideAdWords = "<?php if ($HideAdWords) { echo "yes"; } else { echo "no"; } ?>
```

now your js variable hideAdWords can have either "yes" or "no". And you can use that as js variable.
Did you mean something like that

Comment: This sounds like it may work but due to my uselessness and lack of JS knowledge I can't quite figure out how you mean to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at some of the Google Analytics extensions for Virtuemart?

[BIT Virtuemart Google Analytics](http://extensions.virtuemart.net/component/sobi2/?sobi2Task=sobi2Details&catid=11&sobi2Id=762&Itemid=2)

[Google Analytics for Virtuemart](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-stats/15669)

I have no experience with them, but they seem to have a lot of options.

Comment: Thank you for posting them. I did look at those but this website is currently being migrated to 3DCart so I was just after a quick fix as I don't think I'll have the same problems with 3DCart, but time will tell.